# Is it possible to open a terminal in python and run apps

Tags: python-3.x, import

I try to run a python script that opens terminal and runs an app it shows the following error messages

```
 Use '--' to terminate the options  and put the command line to execute it
```

Heres the code

```
 import os 
 os.system('gnome-terminal -e cvlc music --play-and-exit')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option `-e` seems to be deprecated in recent Gnome versions, in favor of ending your options list with `--`. My guess is that you want

```
import os
os.system('gnome-terminal -- cvlc music --play-and-exit')
```

Comment: This answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116385/option-e-is-deprecated-and-might-be-removed-in-a-later-version-of-gnome-termi might also be useful